# React AG Data Grid: Printing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to implement the print feature of Ag grid. I am using React with typeScript. I observed that the style, width and height property are not accessible in my document.querySelector() method, it throws a squiggly line in my code and those are what actually make the content of the page print. Pls anyone who can help me with this bottleneck.

Here are my codes below for better clarification

function Call

```
  const onFirstDataRendered = params => {
  params.api.expandAll();
  };
 function setPrinterFriendly(api) {
 const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
 eGridDiv.style.height = '';
 api.setDomLayout('print');
 }
 function setNormal(api) {
 const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
 eGridDiv.style.width = '700px';
 eGridDiv.style.height = '200px';
api.setDomLayout(null);
}
 const onBtnPrint = () => {
 const api = gridApi;
 setPrinterFriendly(api);
 setTimeout(function () {
  print();
  setNormal(api);
 }, 2000);
};
```

JSX

```
   <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '500px' }} id="myGrid">
    <AgGridReact
      rowData={tableData}
      defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
      pagination={true}
      paginationPageSize={12}
      enableBrowserTooltips={true}
      ref={gridRef}
      suppressExcelExport={true}
      popupParent={popupParent}
      rowSelection={'multiple'}
      suppressRowClickSelection={true}
      overlayNoRowsTemplate={overlayNoRowsTemplate}
      animateRows={true}
      onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}
    ></AgGridReact>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally resolved the error. I noticed it was an error relating to typescript so I had to tackle the lines of codes pointing to the error

Below is the correct version

```
function setPrinterFriendly(api) {
const eGridDiv = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('#myGrid');
eGridDiv.style.height = '';
api.setDomLayout('print');
}
function setNormal(api) {
const eGridDiv = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('#myGrid');
eGridDiv.style.width = '1100px';
eGridDiv.style.height = '500px';
api.setDomLayout(null);
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` might be better here.

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Mark. I tried it but it throws a TypeError: Cannot read properties of null at setPrinterFriendly()

Comment: It's not super clear what `gridApi` is which is likely the root of that error. FWIW the use of `setTimeout(function () {` likely is a code smell and something else needs to be done differently;